# why i'am getting compilation error in code blocks that i'm using variables out of scope?

Tags: c++, sorting

### error messagein code blocks

while selection sort , in line when calling swap function the error is popping up as

> **error : name lookup of 'j' changed for ISO for scoping **

```
void selectionsort(int size, int A[]){

    for(int i = 0; i<size -1 ; i++){

        int min =i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<size;j++){
            if(A[min]>A[j])
                {min = j;}
        }

        swap(A[min],A[j]);}
}
```

Comment: You have defined `j` inside for loop. Thus, it's scope is only within that for loop. Define it outside the loop and it should be fine.

Comment: I barely remember what a selection sort is, but I think it is more probable you want to move the `swap` invocation inside the inner loop, rather than expanding the scope of the `j` variable.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Selection Sort finds the minimum element in every iteration and swaps it with the index variable `i` of the outer loop. So, in every iteration from `[0, size)`, we find the lowest element and swap it with the start index of the iteration. Thus, `swap(A[min], A[j])` should actually be `swap(A[min], A[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `j` in the initialization of the inner loop, which limits its scope to that loop. If you want to use it outside of the loop, you should define it outside of it. E.g.:

```
void selectionsort(int size, int A[]){

    for(int i = 0; i<size -1 ; i++){

        int min =i;
        int j; // defined outside the loop
        for (j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
            if (A[min] > A[j]) { // used inside it
                min = j;
            }
        }

        swap(A[min], A[j]); // and outside it
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is more likely the OP wants `swap` moved inside the loop. Using the final value of a loop variable isn't idiomatic. If they wanted that they'd just use `size`.

Answer (score 0):

A scope of a variable refers to the block of code which can access it. You cannot access that variable outside that block of code. So, when you define the integer `j` within that for loop, you can only access that code within that for loop. To access it outside the loop, you'll have to declare it outside the for loop.

One extra thing to note is that when there are multiple declarations of the same name, the compiler will resolve to the one closest to it. For ex:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int a = 10;                         // Statement 1
    // We have only one declaration of a till now.
    std::cout << "Value of a before: " << a << std::endl;

    // This will declare a inside loop, hence it's visibility will
    // only be in the loop.
    for(int a = 1; a < 5; a++) {        // Statement 2
        /*
        When we refer a in the cout statement, it can refer to the
        one define outside the loop in Statement 1 or inside the 
        loop in Statement 2. The way compiler is designed it will
        always look for the closest declaration (Statement 2 in 
        this case) and work accordingly.
        */
        std::cout << "Value of a inside loop: " << a << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;


    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)          // Statement 3
        std::cout << "Value of i inside loop: " << i << std::endl;

    int i = 10;                         // Statement 4
    /*
    i has been declared in Statement 3 and Statement 4.
    However, the one declared in Statement 3 can only be accessed 
    within the for loop. Thus, the following statement will refer 
    to the declaration in Statement 4.
    */
    std::cout << "Value of i after loop: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Also, in your case, you probably want to swap with `A[i]` as in `swap(A[min], A[i])`. So, the code should be following:

```
void selectionsort(int size, int A[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i< size-1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
            if(A[min] > A[j])
                min = j;
        }
        swap(A[min], A[i]);
    }
}
```